# Question about how Linked List references and stores data

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a question about how Linked List stores datas and references each other.

```
public class LinkedList {

    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;

        // Constructor
        Node(int d)
        {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Node first = new Node(1);
        Node second = new Node(2);
        Node third = new Node(3);
        Node fourth = new Node(4);
        Node fifth = new Node(5);

        first.next = second;
        second.next = third;
        third.next = fourth;
        fourth.next = fifth;

        second = fourth;
        System.out.println(second.data + "is fourth");
        while (first != null) {
            System.out.println(first.data);
            first = first.next;

        }
    }
}
```

This code prints out

```
4 is fourth
1
2
3
4
5
```

However, I thought it should be

```
4 is fourth
1
4
5
```

Because I changed "second" value to "fourth" value

Anyone could explain what is happening here?

Comment: you aren't changing any value. second is referencing fourth which contains the value of new Node(4). You need to write first.next = fourth to get the desired output

Comment: You changed second to fourth, not second's next to fourth.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I am not trying to get my desired output, but want to know why it still prints out "4 12345" when "second.data" prints out 4. could you please elaborate this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand what happens when you call a method or create a new variable in memory in order to understand this behavior. Basically, there are two portions in memory where data is stored for something like this - the stack and the heap. The stack stores static information and has a fixed size, whereas the heap can store more complicated data (i.e. objects) and has no defined limitation on size, aside from the amount of memory you have available in the first place.

When you instantiate an object in Java, the object itself (the values and properties) are defined and stored in the heap, whereas a reference to the data, or the memory address of the object in the heap, is stored in the variable on the stack. This is why when you do something along the lines of

```
ExampleObject o = new ExampleObject();
System.out.println(o);
```

prints out something like `ExampleObject@fa243dsf`

This output isn't the object itself, which may have certain properties that you have defined, rather it outputs the reference to the object itself. When you do something like `o.exampleProperty` what you've done is dereferenced the object, meaning you told Java to go into the memory address of the object and get the `exampleProperty` value.

Now to come back to your question, the exact same thing happens with the `next` property on each `Node`, it's not storing the object itself, but a reference to that object. Let's imagine these are the memory address locations for each of the `Node` instances you created (just for example purposes, these aren't the exact locations where they are being stored by Java on your machine, nor are they proper memory addresses):

```
first has an address of 111
second has an address of 222
third has an address of 333
fourth has an address of 444
fifth has an address of 555
```

Now, your LL looks like this after assigning the next values:

```
first.next = Node@222
second.next = Node@333
third.next = Node@444
fourth.next = Node@555
fifth.next = null
```

Now, when Java reaches the line `second = fourth`, you haven't changed the object data itself, but merely the memory address that the variable `second` points to. What I mean by this is that `second` now points to address `444`, and if you run `System.out.println(second);`, you will now see `Node@444` be outputted to the console, however, you have not modified the original object that `second` referred to, nor have you modified the values of the `LinkedList`. This means that the value at memory address `222` has not changed, and so since `first.next` points to `Node@222`, the value of the `Node` created and stored at address `222` is the same as it was originally. This is why when you print out `second.data` at the end, you get the same value as `fourth.data`, but why the `LinkedList` itself hasn't changed to what you thought it would change to. If this explanation still wasn't very clear, I suggest you look into variables storing/passing data by reference vs by value, as that is the concept that outlines the behavior you are seeing vs what you had expected.

Comment: Hey Sal, I truly truly appreciate of your answer! It become so clear now! Thank you so much ! appreciate it again!